# Change color properties of object (curve) when text to path (curve) in CorelDraw X5

Tags: color, vector, text, corel-draw

Now it is very easy to make text to path (text to curve) in Corel but once you do it, text becomes connected with curve in Object Manager and I cant figure out **how to change outline or fill color only for the curve?** Or in other words is it possible to somehow select only curve when it is connected with text?

Obviously I can solve this with copy of curve so one curve is connected with text and copy is in front as independent but when comes to some change of curve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way. All you have to do is select **Shape tool** and click on curve so only curve is selected.

Comment: :)) eureeka!!!!

Comment: A belated welcome to GD! Please use the checkmark to the left of your answer to indicate that you solved the problem.  This let's the site know that your question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

Or: you can convert to curves (together). And then, only select one of them.

Comment: Hi Tattilar, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!